# Dart http server freezes when content type is set to text/html

Tags: dart, httpserver

I have a very simple Dart `HttpServer` like this:

```
  server.listen((request) async {
    final html = await indexHtml; // Loaded from a file.
    request.response.write(html);
    await request.response.close();
  });
```

That works perfectly (except it shows the HTML as text), but if I set the content-type correctly like this:

```
  server.listen((request) async {
    final html = await indexHtml;
    request.headers.set("Content-type", "text/html");
    request.response.write(html);
    await request.response.close();
  });
```

Then it freezes and never returns a response. I've tried telnetting to it and typing `GET / HTTP/1.1` but it just never returns any data. Not even headers. Chrome just spins forever.

Am I doing something stupid or is this broken?

Comment: Try: `request.headers.contentType = ContentType.html;` instead.

Comment: No effect unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, I was being stupid, and it actually did give me an exception in the logs:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: HttpException: HTTP headers are not mutable
```

I was trying to modify the request headers, not the response headers. Instead of

```
request.headers.set("Content-type", "text/html");
```

it should be

```
request.response.headers.set("Content-type", "text/html");
```

or rather

```
request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.html;
```

as julemand101 suggested.